# How to install FLIBS for fortran (Linux)

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am trying to use a fortran script that make use of `cgi_protocol.mod` and `fcgi_protocol.mod`. I wanted to compile FLIBS as mentioned [Here](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/) . I downloaded the zip file then ran `./configure.sh` but then I am clueless what should be done next. I tried going to `make/makefile` then running `make` inside but got errors:

```
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1208:41:

 1208 |     call qsort_array ( newlist % array , command )
      |                                         1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1133:47:

 1133 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_asciiincreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1135:47:

 1135 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_asciidecreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1139:47:

 1139 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_dictincreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1141:47:

 1141 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_dictdecreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1145:47:

 1145 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_integerincreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1147:47:

 1147 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_integerdecreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1151:47:

 1151 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_realincreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
../../src/strings/m_vstringlist.f90:1153:47:

 1153 |           call qsort_array ( newlist % array , vstrlist_compare_realdecreasing )
      |                                               1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure ‘compare’ at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'f'
make: *** [Makefile:140: ../../lib/linux/x86_64/gfortran/debug/m_vstringlist.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas how to compile FLIBS? I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the broken Fortran code, or how to persuade the Fortran compiler to accept the broken Fortran code?

Comment: How to install FLIBS basically, I am not sure what I did is correct, the docs aren't clear

Comment: The code is probably broken and incompatible with modern compilers. I tried to check whether there is a newer version on github, but I was not successful. There is a much more recent alternative project https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib  (Arjen Markus, the author of FLIBS, is also active there https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib).